# Unable to store checked value of checkbox in ArrayList

Tags: android, checkbox

The problem I am facing is that I am unable to store the checked value of my checkbox

Here is my code:

```
  final Button markpresent = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
      markpresent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(View v) 
          {
              // Perform action on click
             Toast.makeText(display.this,"You have selected to mark the present students",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

             SparseBooleanArray checked = lView.getCheckedItemPositions();

               ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
               for (int i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) 
               {
                   if (checked.get(i)) 
                   {
                       items.add(arr2[i]);
                       System.out.println(items);
                   }
               }

               Log.d("", "items:");
               for (String string : items)
               {
                   Log.d("", string);
                   System.out.println(items);
               }


          }
      });
```

Only when the button is pressed ,  I want the values checked by the user to be stored in a String. However, my code isn't working fine.

Here is logcat:

```
 11-09 15:52:09.678: WARN/ActivityManager(58): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{44ffd9d0 com.example/.display}
 11-09 15:52:14.856: DEBUG/KeyguardViewMediator(58): pokeWakelock(5000)
 11-09 15:52:15.187: DEBUG/KeyguardViewMediator(58): pokeWakelock(5000)
 11-09 15:52:15.366: INFO/ActivityManager(58): Displayed activity com.example/.display: 16621 ms (total 16621 ms)
 11-09 15:52:15.746: INFO/ARMAssembler(58): generated scanline__00000077:03545404_00000004_00000000 [ 47 ipp] (67 ins) at [0x33ab00:0x33ac0c] in 1153961 ns
 11-09 15:52:15.916: INFO/ARMAssembler(58): generated scanline__00000177:03515104_00001001_00000000 [ 91 ipp] (114 ins) at [0x33ac10:0x33add8] in 921629 ns
 11-09 15:52:21.776: DEBUG/(276): items:
 11-09 15:52:28.086: WARN/KeyCharacterMap(276): No keyboard for id 0
 11-09 15:52:28.086: WARN/KeyCharacterMap(276): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
 11-09 15:52:28.296: WARN/InputManagerService(58): Starting input on non-focused client com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@450bebc0 (uid=10060 pid=276)
 11-09 15:54:46.557: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(293): Shutting down VM
```

Comment: What is the type of `arr2`? `String` array or `int` array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

store the value in sharedPreferences and when you need again just retrieve from sharedPreferences and do your task.

Comment: yes, I have heard of SharedPreferences before. Basically, I need to send those checked values to a remote database via a webservice, that's my intention in storing the data. I want to store it in a String array preferably because I already have a web service that inserts String array into database. But I want to know can the SharedPreferences file also be sent using the way I want as a parameter to my webservice?